# Method implementation that takes 3 parameters and returns a binary number

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I found a method that converts 1 number to a binary number.

```
function dec2bin(dec){
    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}
```

How to implement a method that takes 3 parameters (or more if possible) and turns them into one binary number.

for example:

Encrypt user with parameters

1. Age (up to 255-> 11111111)
2. Number of vacations (up to 15-> 1111)
3. On vacation or not (1 or 0)

create(30, 13, 1);

Expected to get 3 stacked together (00011110) (1101) (1): 0001111011011

Comment: I don't know why use `(dec >>> 0).toString(2)`, when can use `dec.toString(2)`.

Comment: You should "tell" the function how to break the input, as you did in the question's **text**:
8, 4, 1 (255, 15, 1).
so, pass/hard code an array with those "or more if possible" binary lengths.
Then it will be a simple matter to do with about one line of code...

Comment: what should be done if 'dec' is not decimal, not a number, negative, larger than a certain threshold (255, 15, 1, ?)?

Comment: Borrowing from answers (@Lemondoge) below:
`function dec2bin(dec, digits) {
  if(typeof(dec)=="number" && dec%1==0 && dec>=0 and dec<Math.pow(2, digits))
    return dec.toString(2).padStart(digits, "0");
  return undefined;
}`

Comment: Then you can use:
`function encrypt(userDetailsArray, encriptDigitsArray) {
  if(userDetailsArray.length<=encriptDigitsArray.length)
    return userDetailsArray.map((detail, index)=>dec2bin(detail, encriptDigitsArray[index])).join("");
  return undefined;
}`

Comment: combined into an answer...

Comment: may I get your opinion about my answer?

Comment: There are no `bitwise-operations` done here, the `>>> 0` is useless and not needed.

Comment: You could have edited this question with additional information instead of creating a [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623282/find-numbers-that-have-specified-data-about-people)...

Comment: @mplungjan, the op is LITERALLY all over the place, and so are the comments - please expand on "like solution 2 in...".  I was showing 2 aspects of same scenario being split into two questions BY THE SAME OP... :)

Comment: @mplungjan, the uselessness(?) of `(dec >>> 0)`?
comments are not guaranteed to remain in order (afaik)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirement Encrypt user with parameters age (up to 255-> 11111111), Number of vacations (up to 15-> 1111), On vacation or not (1 or 0)

```js
const create = (age, noOfVacations, onVacation) => {
  return (
    age.toString(2).padStart(8, '0') +
    noOfVacations.toString(2).padStart(4, '0') +
    onVacation.toString(2).padStart(1, '0')
  );
};
const ret = create(30, 13, 1);
console.log(ret);
```

By the way, you can refactor the above code to make it more reusable by making a separated binary to decimal with zero padding function.

```js
const binToDecWithZeroPad = (param, n) => param.toString(2).padStart(n, '0');

const create = (age, noOfVacations, onVacation) =>
  binToDecWithZeroPad(age, 8) +
  binToDecWithZeroPad(noOfVacations, 4) +
  binToDecWithZeroPad(onVacation, 1);

const ret = create(30, 13, 1);
console.log(ret);
```

If parameter number is unknown you can use rest parameter. Rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array. So you can use any number of parameter.

```js
const create = (...params) => {
  let str = '';
  params.forEach((x) => (str += x.toString(2)));
  return str;
};
const ret = create(30, 13, 1);
console.log(ret);
```

**Update:**
I have not to checked if the parameter is a non numeric, decimal or negative in my code because if you need to check it you can easily add it by using simple if condition and as for adding zero dynamically you cannot use more than one rest parameter because this is the limitation that only one rest parameter is allowed in the function declaration. Although, you can solve it by using one rest parameter(think about it if you have time). By the way, you can also use object, single or multiple array whatever you want as a parameter to make it dynamic.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted?
It does not give 13 binary digit answer...
It gives 
1111011011 when it should give 
0001111011011.

Comment: When you use indefinite parameter then how could you say it will be always 13 binary digits.

Comment: Are you happy now?

Comment: It's not a matter of me being happy.
It's a matter of code giving expected results.
Your code still doesn't give expected results:
op asked for 8-digit + 4-digit + 1-digit concatenated string - in the **text**.
The op is unclear about what to do if more or less than 3 parameters are supplied.

Comment: OP also confused about if more than 3 inputs.

Comment: yep - "or more if possible", but no details about what to do with them... :)

Comment: @iAmOren I have fulfilled OP's requirement and do not know about negative param because there is no instruction about it.

Comment: @mrhr thanks, your example works good, I didn't immediately understand that if you get the result dynamically, then I won't be able to control the number of unused zeros :)

Comment: @mrhr, may I get your opinion about my answer?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```js
function dec2bin(dec){
  return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}
function create(age, vacationNumber, vacation) {
  var a = dec2bin(age).padStart(8, "0"); // padEnd adds zeros to match size
  var b = dec2bin(vacationNumber).padStart(4, "0");
  var c = vacation==true||vacation==1 ? 1 : 0;
  return a + b + c;
}
console.log(create(15, 20, 1))
```

Comment: Did you mean `padStart`?

Comment: No. padStart would add zeros to the back, which would be difficult if not impossible to convert back to decimal.

Comment: 15 in binary is 1111.
If we need 8 digits, it will be 00001111.
not 11110000 as your solution, which is 240...

Comment: Here to help!
What should we do if less than 3, no, or more than 3 arguments?
op only knows... :)

Comment: may I get your opinion about my answer?

Comment: @iAmOren do you have a link to articles that will help me understand how to extract data from an encrypted string?
For example, I have an array of generated numbers and I need to find everyone who is between the ages of 20 and 30 inclusive?

Comment: @Alice, what do you mean by encrypted?
What we did here is not real encryption.
Can you share the array?
And what do you know about the values in the array?

Comment: @iAmOren encrypt is a simple term. I just need to find from a similar set of numbers those numbers in which the search condition will match. If I create a ticket in which I describe in more detail, will you help me?

Comment: @Alice, I don't know what a "ticket" is (in this context), but, if you add the details of the array and what you know about it's values - to your question by means of edit, and notify me - I will take a look and try to help.

Comment: @iAmOren hello, please check my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623282/find-numbers-that-have-specified-data-about-people

Comment: @Alice, see my revised answer.
It would be nice of you to accept and up-vote it...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function `encrypt` that works on an array of any number of arguments, as long as you provide long enough encript digits array, and inputs are non-negative integers - if any of the conditions are not met, `undefined` is returned:

```js
function dec2bin(dec, digits) {
  if(typeof(dec)=="number" && dec%1==0 && dec>=0 && dec<Math.pow(2, digits))
    return dec.toString(2).padStart(digits, "0");
  return undefined;
}
function encrypt(userDetailsArray, encriptDigitsArray) {
  if(userDetailsArray.length<=encriptDigitsArray.length) {
    var result=(
      userDetailsArray.map(
        (detail, index) => dec2bin(detail, encriptDigitsArray[index])
      )
    );
    if(result.includes(undefined))
      return undefined;
    else
      return result.join("");
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(encrypt([30,13,1],[8,4,1])); /* your example */
console.log(encrypt([30,13],[8,4,1])); /* less input */
console.log(encrypt([30],[8,4,1])); /* even less input */
console.log(encrypt([30,13,1,100,5],[8,4,1,7,4])); /* more input and encript digits */
console.log(encrypt([999,13,1],[8,4,1])); /* bad input */
console.log(encrypt([30,13,1],[8,4])); /* not enough encript digits */
```

Decrypt (without testing validity of arguments):

```js
function decrypt(bin, encriptDigitsArray) {
  var result=[];
  while(bin!="" && encriptDigitsArray.length) {
    result.push(parseInt(bin.slice(0,encriptDigitsArray[0]), 2));
    bin=bin.slice(encriptDigitsArray[0]);
    encriptDigitsArray.shift();
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(decrypt("0001111011011",[8,4,1]));
console.log(decrypt("000111101101",[8,4,1]));
console.log(decrypt("00011110",[8,4,1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @mrhr, thank you!
I hope I've covered all cases...
Thanks for the up-vote!
(If it wasn't you - hint... hint... :) )