# Find numbers that have specified data about people

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is an array of binary numbers that are created in this order

the first number means whether the person is on vacation: 1/0
the second set of 8 numbers means the worker's age: 255 maximum (11111111)
the third set of 4 numbers means how many vacations are left: maximum 15 vacations (1111)

How to find:

1. all worker on vacation, aged 20-30 inclusive
2. all worker are not on vacation with the number of vacation 10 or more

An array of workers data:

```
let workers = [
    0b1000101001001,
    0b1000101111011,
    0b1000111101011,
    0b0000101101010,
    0b0000111011111,
    0b0000110011110,
    0b1001000011001,
    0b1001000011001,
    0b0000101101000,
    0b0000101100100,
];
```

Comment: A "number" =/= a "digit".

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: The second and third entry in `workers` are exactly the same, yet the comment is different?? The 7th and 8th are exactly the same, yet the comment is different?? The last two numbers are exactly the same, yet the comment is different?? The fifth entry has 0 as the least significant bit, yet it has an odd number of vacation days?? How did you get 9 days of vacation from the 6th entry?? Please, ... there are so many errors here, that it shows you didn't do much of an effort here.

Comment: @trincot I got a little confused, these numbers are very easy to get confused. Everything is fixed

Comment: No, not everything is fixed. Please check each of my comments again.

Comment: @NinaScholz This is the notation of a binary number

Comment: This is a continuation of your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614405/method-implementation-that-takes-3-parameters-and-returns-a-binary-number) that you should have edited to include the extra information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know whether the number `i` encodes "on vacation" or not, evaluate:

```
i >= 0x1000
```

If this is true, that worker is on vacation

To know the age that the number `i` encodes, evaluate:

```
(i >> 4) & 0xFF
```

To know the number of vacation days that is encoded, evaluate:

```
i & 0xFF
```

The rest should be simple to do.

> all workers on vacation, aged 20-30 inclusive

```js
let workers = [0b1000101001001, 0b1000101111011, 0b1000111101011, 0b0000101101010, 0b0000111011111, 0b0000110011110, 0b1001000011001, 0b1001000011001, 0b0000101101000, 0b0000101100100, ];
let result = workers.filter(i => {
  let onVac = i >= 0x1000;
  let age = (i >> 4) & 0xFF;
  return onVac && age >= 20 && age <= 30;
});
console.log(result.map(num => num.toString(2)))
```

> all workers that are not on vacation with the number of vacation 10 or more

```js
let workers = [0b1000101001001, 0b1000101111011, 0b1000111101011, 0b0000101101010, 0b0000111011111, 0b0000110011110, 0b1001000011001, 0b1001000011001, 0b0000101101000, 0b0000101100100, ];
let result = workers.filter(i => {
  let onVac = i >= 0x1000;
  let numVac = i & 0xFF;
  return !onVac && numVac >= 10;
});

console.log(result.map(num=>num.toString(2)))
```

Sometimes you can filter with fewer operations, but this at least shows clearly the final expression that is evaluated in the filter callback.

## Other patterns

In general, to extract a part of a bitpattern, you first shift the input and then AND it. Here the part to extract is indicated with `^`:

```
input = 0b1111111111111111111111111
                    ^^^^^^^^
                    ←   8  →←  7  →
```

First count the number of bits (digits) that are at the right of the section you need. In this case there are 7 bits to the right of the `^`-marked section. This determines how many times you need to shift with the `>>` operator.

Then you count the number of bits that are *in* the section of interest. In this case the `^` section has a width of 8 bits. Now make a number that has 8 bits, and all of them 1-bits: 0b11111111. You can of course choose to write it in hexadecimal or in decimal, ... it doesn't matter, as long as the value is the same. This number will be the number you perform the AND (`&`) operation with.

So in the above example, you combine as follows:

```
(input >> 7) & 0b11111111
```

There are of course a few cases where you can shorten this expression:

#### Extract left most bits

If the section you need, is the *left*-most section in the bit pattern, then the AND-operation is not needed:

```
input = 0b1111111111111111111111111
          ^^^^^^^^                 
          ←   8  →←      17       →
```

Here both of the following give the same result:

```
(input >> 17) & 0b11111111
input >> 17
```

#### Extract right most bits

If the section you need, is the *right*-most section in the bit pattern, then the AND-operation is not needed:

```
input = 0b1111111111111111111111111
                           ^^^^^^^^                 
                           ←   8  →
```

Here both of the following give the same result:

```
(input >> 0) & 0b11111111
input & 0b11111111
```

#### Extract left most bit -- just one bit

If the section you need, is the *left*-most single bit in the bit pattern, then you can also use a greater-or-equal comparison to return a boolean:

```
input = 0b1111111111111111111111111
          ^
           ←          24          →
```

You can know whether this bit it set with a comparison. Here all of the following give a useful same result:

```
(input >> 24) & 0b1
input >> 24
input >= 0b1000000000000000000000000
```

...but with one difference: the third evaluates to a boolean, while the other two evaluate to a 0 or a 1.

Comment: What does '0x1000' and '0xFF' mean? How do I understand what code I need if I want to come up with other filters?

Comment: `0x` is an indication of a hexadecimal notation, just like `0b` is an indication of binary notation. 0xFF == 0b11111111 == 255, and 0x1000 == 0b1000000000000 == 4096. *"How do I understand..."*: see first part of the answer, and how that part is used in the second part of my answer.

Comment: I cannot understand the moment of data validation. If I have a slightly different data plotting algorithm.
Conditional: `1,1,11111111,1111,1`
And I need to find: `1,0,(up to 20),0,1`

I check by the first byte, but I can check the second byte, could you tell me why?

`let one = persons.filter(i => {
    let condition1 = i >= 0b100000000000000;
    let condition2 = (i >> 1) & i >= 0b100000000000000;
    let condition3 = (i >> 2) & 0b11111111;
    let condition4 = (i >> 14) & i >= 0b100000000000000;
    return condition1 && !condition2 && condition3 >= 20 && condition4;
});`

Comment: `i` should not appear at the right of `&`. I added a section to my answer with "the method" that should work for getting any section from a bit pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypt:

```js
function decrypt(bin, encriptDigitsArray) {
  var result=[];
  while(bin!="" && encriptDigitsArray.length) {
    result.push(parseInt(bin.slice(0,encriptDigitsArray[0]), 2));
    bin=bin.slice(encriptDigitsArray[0]);
    encriptDigitsArray.shift();
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(decrypt("0001111011011",[8,4,1]));
console.log(decrypt("000111101101",[8,4,1]));
console.log(decrypt("00011110",[8,4,1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64615067/5792509) for you other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614405/method-implementation-that-takes-3-parameters-and-returns-a-binary-number).